# Lambda operator in set

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

Can someone explain what the purpose of the lambda operator is in this piece of code, what does it do?

```
public string HelloWorld
{
    get { return _helloWorld; }
    set { Set(() => HelloWorld, ref _helloWorld, value); }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to guess the purpose of the lambda without knowing how the `Set` method works.

Comment: It's from the MVVM Light stack(ObservableObject.Set), but I can't find any docs about it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common pattern to extract the member name for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Usually, you would want to raise the `PropertyChanged` event with a [`PropertyChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.aspx) with the property name that changed. The problem is that the property name is a string. So if you rename the property, you will have to make sure that you adjust all member name strings too.

In order to avoid that, people often implement some method, e.g. your `Set`, that takes an expression. The method then uses the expression tree to extract the member name of the property. It then takes the name to create the event arguments and raises the event for you.

---

Your `Set` is likely equivalent to the following setter:

```
set
{
    if (_helloWorld != value)
    {
        _helloWorld = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(this, "HelloWorld"));
    }
}
```

And all that is encapsulated in the `Set` method which is provided by the base view model.

---

Btw. with .NET 4.5, you can make use of the new compiler services to make this even simpler. .NET 4.5 comes with the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) which allows implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to provide a utility function that automatically gets the name of the property, so you don’t have to pass a lambda expression that references the property. Furthermore, this new functionality is evaluated at compile time, so you get the same performance as when you pass just a string, except that you don’t need to specify that string anywhere, so you’re safe against refactorings.

This functionality is also provided by MVVM Light, and you can use a different overload of `Set` to use it. Your example would then just look like this:

```
Set(ref _helloWorld, value);
```

With C# 6, you can also use the new [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx): `nameof(HelloWorld)` will be replaced by `"HelloWorld"` at compile time.

Comment: So the set method basically just sets the backfield property and dispatches the PropertyChange event?

Instead of launching the event in every single setter, you use the set method. Got it!

Comment: @Mazzy Yes exactly, and since you refer to the property inside the lambda expression, when you rename the property using VS’ refactoring tools, the reference inside the lambda updates too. So it will still raise the event for the correct property.

Comment: I know that pattern. Yes it's common - but why does it work? The use case is that changing the property name will probably raise the event having the old name. Okay. Got it. But there are a lot of event handlers registered to this event (I don't mean object binding to UI, I mean self written event handlers). They check for the name as string. Is there a way to change the checked names? Maybe C# 6 will help with `nameof`.

Comment: @Verarind It’s really only for raising the property. The idea is that it’s highly redundant that you would have to specify the name of the property inside the same property’s setter. It’s not really helpful for event observers checking for changed properties. There, you still need to check the name explicitely, although you can still use a similar utility function that allows you to refer to the property in a expression (e.g. an extension method `PropertyChangedEventArgs.IsProperty<MyType>(obj => obj.HelloWorld)`). And if you have an object of the desired type you can also use `nameof` there.

Comment: Worth to mention [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) too.